# Multiple (nested) Subtotal VBA Code with Inserting Sum Formula in the Subtotal

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to create a nested subtotal macro, meaning to have one subtotal for column “countries” and one subtotal for column “cities.” I use the below code to get the subtotal for countries, but I don’t know how to expand the code to get subtotal for cities.

One condition in my code is that the sum formula should exist in the subtotal row to make sure having the correct range.

I tried different ways to get the subtotal for cities, but the range of sum formula will be changed as the macro inserts a new to create for a new subtotal.

My idea is to have a code in two steps:

1. Get the subtotal for countries as hard values ---> having hard values help us avoid the distortion of formula as macro creates subtotal for cities
2. Get the subtotal for cities as sum formulas 
   Here is the current code I used to create subtotal for countries as sum formula inside.

The Code I use for creating a subtotal for column countries:

```
Dim iCol As Integer 'number of columns
Dim i As Integer 'Macro starts from this row number
Dim j As Integer 'Macro continues with this row number in the loop

Worksheets("Example").Activate

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
i = 2 'starts from row 2
j = i
'Loops throught Col A Checking for match then when there is no match add Sum
Do While Range("A" & i) <> ""
    If Range("A" & i) <> Range("A" & (i + 1)) Then
        Rows(i + 1).Insert
        Range("A" & (i + 1)) = "Subtotal " & Range("A" & i).Value
        For iCol = 3 To 4 'Columns to Sum
            Cells(i + 1, iCol).Formula = "=SUM(R" & j & "C:R" & i & "C)"
        Next iCol
        Range(Cells(i + 1, 1), Cells(i + 1, 4)).Font.Bold = True
        Range(Cells(i + 1, 1), Cells(i + 1, 4)).Interior.Color = RGB(221, 237, 245)
        i = i + 2
        j = i
    Else
        i = i + 1
    End If
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Here is the screenshot of what I would like to have after running the code.

[image: Original Data Before Implemeting the code]

This is my desired output

[image: This is my desired output]

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you check out PivotTables? See [Excel Pivot Table Subtotals](https://www.contextures.com/excel-pivot-table-subtotals.html)

Comment: Yes, but this macro Code is part of another bigger macro where every single part is being imported from differet MIS Systems, and using Pivot table on them is impossible. The table I just represented is not my real date, but to simplify my Question so that experts here understand what I look for.

Comment: What is 'SUMME'?  I've never heard of that before.  Maybe some kind of international setting/configuration, or you are concatenating some characters into your SUM function.

Comment: @asher It's a German Excel so the formulas are localized (german). `SUMME` is actually `SUM`.

Comment: Oh, I see.  How about firing up the macro recorder then adding subtotals by clicking through the logic you need?  I think that will give you the VBA you need.  I just did the same thing less than 1 hour ago.

Comment: @asher, sorry, my operating System is in German and that is why Excel is in German.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this is much more complicated then it looks like:

It can do this for unlimited criteria columns and unlimited subtotal sum rows. Just don't forget to adjust the costants:

```
Const StartRow As Long = 2      'omit headers
Const CriteriaCount As Long = 3 'amount of criteria columns (here countries + cities + Houses)
Const SumtotalCount As Long = 3 'amount columns to sumtotal
```

The code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CreateSubtotals()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Example")

    Const StartRow As Long = 2      'omit headers
    Const CriteriaCount As Long = 3 'amount of criteria columns (here countries + cities + Hauses)
    Const SumtotalCount As Long = 3 'amount columns to sumtotal

    Dim Criteria() As Variant
    Criteria = ws.Cells(StartRow, 1).Resize(ColumnSize:=CriteriaCount).Value

    ReDim StartRows(1 To CriteriaCount)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(StartRows) To UBound(StartRows)
        StartRows(i) = StartRow
    Next i

    Dim iRow As Long, iCol As Long
    iRow = StartRow + 1

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim RowsAdded As Long, CriteriaChanged As Boolean

    Do While iRow < LastRow + 2
        For iCol = CriteriaCount To 1 Step -1
            CriteriaChanged = False
            For i = 1 To iCol
                If Criteria(1, i) <> ws.Cells(iRow, i).Value Then CriteriaChanged = True
            Next i

            If CriteriaChanged Then
                ws.Rows(iRow).Insert
                RowsAdded = RowsAdded + 1

                ws.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = "Subtotal " & Criteria(1, iCol)
                If iCol = CriteriaCount Then
                    ws.Cells(iRow, CriteriaCount + 1).Resize(ColumnSize:=SumtotalCount).Formula = "=Sum(" & ws.Cells(StartRows(iCol), CriteriaCount + 1).Resize(RowSize:=iRow - StartRows(iCol)).Address(True, False) & ")"
                Else
                    ws.Cells(iRow, CriteriaCount + 1).Resize(ColumnSize:=SumtotalCount).Formula = "=Sumif(" & ws.Cells(StartRows(iCol), iCol + 1).Resize(RowSize:=iRow - StartRows(iCol)).Address(True, True) & ",""Subtotal*""," & ws.Cells(StartRows(iCol), CriteriaCount + 1).Resize(RowSize:=iRow - StartRows(iCol)).Address(True, False) & ")"
                End If

                ws.Cells(iRow, iCol).Resize(ColumnSize:=SumtotalCount + CriteriaCount - iCol + 1).Interior.ThemeColor = 7 + iCol 'whatever you want

                For i = iCol To UBound(StartRows)
                    StartRows(i) = 0
                Next i
                iRow = iRow + 1
            End If
        Next iCol

        If RowsAdded <> 0 Then
            Criteria = ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Resize(ColumnSize:=CriteriaCount).Value
            For i = LBound(StartRows) To UBound(StartRows)
                If StartRows(i) = 0 Then StartRows(i) = iRow
            Next i

            LastRow = LastRow + RowsAdded 'if we insert a row we must increas last row
            RowsAdded = 0
        End If

        iRow = iRow + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! What you wrote is a strong macro. Your help means a lot.